# Bash how to print out all the input arguments without using loop

Tags: bash, shell

I've heard of that loop in bash is in efficient and complicated. so i'm try to make a script that print out all the argument in a specific format without using any loop.

When i do

```
bash script_name arg1 arg2 arg3...
```

or

```
./script_name arg1 arg2 arg3...
```

it should output:

```
0: script_name
1: arg1
2: arg2
...
```

I try to use $@ but the problem is it never prints out the script name, and i'm having trouble to come up with a way to print out the index.

can anyone pls give me a hint? thank you

Comment: You heard wrong, unless you are using a 286 PC? Any medium modern CPU should have no trouble with efficiency when operating on data that is in memory. 2nd, when/why would printing arguments faster be an advantage? 3rd any code that you write in a shell that produces the output you need will be more complex, harder to enhance and  harder to understand by someone else. Life it too short, use the tools your environment gives you for free ;-) !! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `$@` does not contain the script name, it only contains the actual command-line arguments. You have to print `$0` explicitly to print the script name.

Here are two solutions:

```
exec paste -d: <(seq 0 $#;) <(printf ' %s\n' "$0" "$@";);
```

The above runs the `paste` utility to paste together (1) a sequence of numbers from 0 to the number of arguments given, generated by the `seq` utility, and (2) the script name and command-line arguments, printed by `printf`, one per line. Each of the `seq` and `printf` commands is run in a process substitution construct, with each generated device file representing the command output (e.g. `/dev/fd/63` on my system) passed to `paste`.

```
exec printf '%s\n' "$0" "$@"| awk '{ print(i++": "$0); };';
```

The above prints the script name and command-line arguments, one per line, and pipes them to `awk`, which adds the desired numbering prefix.

It should be noted that each of these two solutions involves starting at least one additional system process, either for process substitution or for a pipeline. That is pretty much guaranteed to be much *more* inefficient than running the bash built-in for-loop, which requires no additional processes (assuming that you only call built-in stuff within the loop, e.g. `printf`). In general, built-in commands/keywords/constructs will almost always be faster than running external executables.

Comment: How exactly does `exec printf` improve `printf` in that case? `printf` is a built-in, and `bash` is always going to spawn a subprocess for the pipe.

Comment: I suppose it is a habit of mine to always use `exec` when I'm executing a guaranteed final command in a script whose return code I want to return from the script. At the very least, it is a kind of documentation to anyone viewing the code that this is explicitly the final command of the script. In general, it also absolves the programmer of the need to determine when the final command is indeed a builtin on all versions of the shell that the script might run on. Finally, although I don't know much about the shell internals, it wouldn't surprise me if it made some kind of optimization possible.

Comment: `bash` will do that particular optimization without any help; that is its limited form of TCO. `zsh` performs TCO more aggressively. FWIW. (And I personally find `|` sufficiently self-documenting. But that's just me. I was just curious.)